# Mapping from a Resolved Member in Automapper

Tags: automapper

This is a reach, but I am going to ask anyway.

I'll lead with my example:

```cs
public class PatientInfoModel : IPatientInfoModel, IHaveCustomMappings
{
    public string PatientId { get; set; }
    public string PatientIdForView { get; set; }
    public PatientEpisodeData PatientEpisode { get; set; }

    public void CreateMappings(Profile configuration)
    {
        configuration.CreateMap<PatientInfoRawDto, PatientInfoModel>()
            .ForMember(m => m.PatientIdForView, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<PatientIdResolver<PatientInfoRawDto, PatientInfoModel>>())
            .ForMember(m => m.PatientId, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.patID))
            .ForMember(m => m.PatientEpisode, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => new PatientEpisodeData
            {
                PatientId = p.patID,
                PatientIdForView = this.PatientIdForView
            }));
    }

    public class PatientEpisodeData
    {
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public string PatientIdForView { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, with the member **PatientEpisode**, I would like to map from one of the properties which has already been resolved (**PatientIdForView**).

As I could not figure out how to do this, I just set the property after the fact. But it would be interesting to find out if this is possible.

Note: I'm not really interested in using a custom value resolver unless you could pass the **PatientIdForView** property to it.

Cheers

Comment: I think this is what they have `.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Name = "John");` for but I could be misunderstanding you're question.

Comment: @MisterIsaak Thanks. I did try AfterMap, but it does not work. The PatientIdForView property is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom value resolvers *do* allow you to pass in the destination member value into it (I assume that's what the PatientIdForView property you mention is, the destination member value). If you need the source member value, you can use a member value resolver:

http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html

You get the destination member, the source member that you specify, and the source/destination objects. Should be everything you need!

Comment: that worked.  I missed that interface when i read the documentation. Tremendous!